# RoR 4.x approach for managing transactions best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions

first of all - sorry for perhaps stupid questions but I'm beginner in RoR world and I need some basic clarity on how database transactions work within models / controllers. I come from Java world where certain things are done in certain way and when working with RoR I naturally compare it to Java web frameworks hence my confusion if something looks radically different :-)

In one of my controller actions, I need to modify and save multiple of models, let's say: Order, Invoice, Payment.

From what I understand, standard "save" method on each model executes in it's own transaction therefore if I would simply write:

```
payment.save
order.save
invoice.save
```

this would create 3 independent DB transactions and each model would be saved in it's own transactions - which is not what I want since I'd like to make sure that either all or none of these models are saved.

I found this article: http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/ which demonstrates how to wrap multiple "saves" into single transaction. It's fairly old but I hope it is still valid (correct me if I'm wrong).

One thing that I don't like is that I need to manage these transactions explicitly in each controller action where I need it. I would prefer this to happen "behind the scenes" like "open session in view" pattern known from Java world where DB transaction is started in a filter before any DB query is executed and transaction is committed in a filter after all controller actions have finished.

I was thinking about using similar approach in my RoR application, I found blog post demonstrating how to do it: http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/10/rails-controllers-and-transactions.html however I'm not sure whether this is "best practice" since the other article (http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/) says that "Use of transactions in a controller is common anti-pattern to avoid" (not sure why though).

Would someone be able to direct me into "right" approach?

thank you,

Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are a model-layer concern. I don't think they belong in the controller, although it would certainly work. It's not a hard rule.

One thing to consider is would this code need to be run outside the context of a controller? For example in a background job? Or a rake task? In that case consolidating the logic into the model layer would make it easier to reuse.

To accomplish this in the model layer, the "Rails way" is to make use of callbacks. The `*_save/create/update` callbacks are automatically executed within the current database transaction, which means you get the desired transaction behavior "for free" without explicitly writing transaction code.

If your models have a clear parent-child relationship, then you can register the callbacks on the "top level" model, e.g.:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :invoice
  has_one :payment

  after_create :save_child_records

  private

  def save_child_records
    invoice.save!
    payment.save!
  end
end

order.save
# triggers invoice.save! and payment.save! 
# all in one transaction
```

Alternatively, you could create a brand new model that is not backed by a database table, that simply serves to orchestrate multiple models. This is sometimes called a "service object" or "operation object".

For this I recommend the [active_type](https://github.com/makandra/active_type) gem, which lets you use all the standard ActiveRecord callbacks, which therefore gives the same desirable transaction behavior:

```
class ProcessPayment < ActiveType::Object
  attr_accessor :order, :invoice, :payment

  # You can declare ActiveRecord validations here too
  # Or register other before_save callbacks for business logic

  before_save :save_records

  private

  def save_records
    order.save!
    invoice.save!
    payment.save!
  end
end

process_payment.save
# order, invoice, payment are all saved in a single transaction
```

Answer (score 2):

A basic transaction can be done like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  payment.save!
  order.save!
  invoice.save!
end
```

What you want, however, is a service object, which will take care of it.

```
class PaymentHadler
  def initialize(payment, order, invoice)
  end
  def perform
  end
end
```

Depending on your app, it might be sensible to provide the parameters hashes to the PaymentHandler and instantiate the models in the handler. In most cases they need to be associated, so built inside the controller. Your mileage may vary :)

Comment: isn't it better to use save! instead of save in this case?

Comment: Yes, if you want to abort the transaction, then use the bang version of save. I'll edit the answer.